# Passing a file from Angular (1.5.7) to asp.net core controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I'm trying to save the image on the server alongside with some information about it using form and then angular (1.5.7) and C#.

I've tried multiple ways, Either the file passed to Api controller is empty or the Model state is invalid.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

My C# Controller:

```
namespace xxx.Controllers.Api
{
[Route("api/partners")]

public class PartnersController : Controller
{
    private IMeblatRepository _repository;
    private ILogger<PartnersController> _logger;
    private IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    public PartnersController(IMeblatRepository repository, ILogger<PartnersController> logger, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _logger = logger;
        _environment = environment;
    }

    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try { 
        var results = _repository.GetAllPartners();

        return Ok(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PartnersViewModel>>(results));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Failed to get All Partners: {ex}");
            return BadRequest("Bad Request");
        }
    }
    [HttpPost("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Data data)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");

                if (data.file.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, data.file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await data.file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                }




            //Save to the Database
            var newPartner = Mapper.Map<Partners>(data.newPartner);





            _repository.AddPartner(newPartner);

            if(await _repository.SaveChangesAsync())
            {
                return Created($"api/partners/{data.newPartner.Name}", Mapper.Map<PartnersViewModel>(newPartner));
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Failed to save to the database");
            }


        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }



    [HttpDelete("{name}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromRoute] string name)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var partnerToDelete = _repository.GetPartnerByName(name);
            _repository.RemovePartner(partnerToDelete);

            if (await _repository.SaveChangesAsync())
            {
                return Ok($"api/partners");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Failed to remove");
            }


        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

}
```

}

Data class:

```
public class Data
{
    public PartnersViewModel newPartner { get; set; }
    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
}
```

Angular controller:

```
(function () {

"use strict";
// getting the existing module
angular.module("app-edit")
    .controller("partnersController", partnersController);


function partnersController($http, $scope) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.partners = [];

    vm.newPartner = {};

    vm.errorMessage = "";
    vm.isBusy = true;
    var f = null;

    $scope.add = function () {
        f = document.getElementById('uploader').files[0];
        if (f) {
            alert("File attached succesfully");
        }
    };

    $http.get("/api/partners").then(function (response) {
        //success
        angular.copy(response.data, vm.partners);
    }, function () {
        //failure
        vm.errorMessage = "failed to load data";
    })
        .finally(function () {
            vm.isBusy = false;
        });

    vm.addPartner = function () {

        vm.isBusy = true;
        vm.errorMessage = "";

        var Indata = { 'newPartner': vm.newPartner, 'file': f };

        $http.post("/api/partners", Indata)
            .then(function () {
                //success
                vm.partners.push(response.data);
                vm.newPartner = {};
            }, function () {
                //failure
                vm.errorMessage = "Failed to save new partner";
            })
            .finally(function () {
                vm.isBusy = false;
            });



    };



    vm.removePartner = function (name) {

        vm.isBusy = true;
        vm.errorMessage = "";

        $http.delete("/api/partners/" + name)
            .then(function () {
                //success
                //vm.partners.shift();
                //vm.newPartner = {};
                 vm.errorMessage = "Udało się usunąć partnera";
            }, function () {
                //failure
                vm.errorMessage = "Nie udało się usunąć partnera";
            })
            .finally(function () {
                vm.isBusy = false;
            });

    };

}

})();
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="text-danger" ng-show="vm.errorMessage">{{ vm.errorMessage }}</div>
<wait-cursor ng-show="vm.isBusy"></wait-cursor>


<form novalidate name="newPartnerForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-submit="vm.addPartner()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nazwa Partnera</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="vm.newPartner.name" required/>
        <span ng-show="newPartnerForm.name.$error.required" class="text-warning">To pole jest wymagane</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="files">Ścieżka</label>
        <input type="file" id="uploader" name="files[]" class="btn btn-primary" accept="image/*" ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="false">
        <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="href">Link do strony partnera</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="href" name="href" ng-model="vm.newPartner.href"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Add"
               class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
               ng-disabled="newPartnerForm.$invalid" />
    </div>
</form>


<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="partner in vm.partners">
        <td> {{partner.name}}</td>
        <td> {{partner.href}}</td>
        <td><a ng-href="#/editor/{{ patner.name }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Manage</a></td>
        <td><input type="button" ng-click="vm.removePartner(partner.name)" value="Usuń" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Passing from form seems to be working as the alert is trigerred everytime I choose the file.

Comment: can you post your html??where are you calling `$scope.add ` in your code ? i am not seeing it inside `vm.addPartner` but the default value of `f` is `null`

Comment: can you use `console.log(Indata)` to see what value is attached in the `f` property

Comment: can you try changing to `var data = { 'newPartner': vm.newPartner, 'file': f };` and then call `$http.post("/api/partners", data)`

Comment: @Niladri I've added the HTML file

Comment: as I said the value of `f` remains null as it is not attached to the scope , can you replace `f` with `vm.f = null;` and then replace `f` with `vm.f` in your code for example in  `$scope.add = function () {
        vm.f = null;
        vm.f = document.getElementById('uploader').files[0];
        if (vm.f) {
            alert("File attached succesfully");
        }
    };`

Comment: and you have to also change `var data = { 'newPartner': vm.newPartner, 'file': vm.f };`

Comment: @Niladri I've made the changes you proposed. My console is showing something like that: "data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"|50ebc896-4d2da626898340f9.","name":"POST Partners/Post","duration":"00:00:00.0862469","success":false,"responseCode":"400","url":"http://localhost:54884/api/partners","properties":{"AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","DeveloperMode":"true","httpMethod":"POST"}}}}.
For some reason clicking the file add button triggers addPartner() function now.

Comment: is this the result of `console.log(data)`? are you able to receive the file now?

Comment: @Niladri Yes. From what I think that is the result of console.log(data), but I still cannot pass the file to the C# controller. If in angular I do alert(vm.f) I get the alert saying [object File] and if I do alert(data) I'm getting [object Object]. What's more in debug mode i can see addPartner() is no longer triggering the Post function from C# controller class and it goes straight into failure function.